# Inheriting from Dictionary class with tuple as value

Tags: c#

I have a class that inherits from Dictionary<Tkey, TValue>.

I need my Value part of the KeyValue pair to be a a Tuple (int, bool )

```
public class IssueRowValidationDictionary :
        Dictionary<string, (int, bool)>
    {
        public IssueRowValidationDictionary() : base() { }

        internal void Add(string issueReference, int rawRowNumber, bool v)
        {
            Add(issueReference, (rawRowNumber, v));
        }
    }
```

In my code there are cases where I need to get the int Value part of the dictionary Element

```
             var intValue = issueRowValidationDictionary['keyRef'].Item1;
```

Is there a more elegant way for Example to create a specific property that will only return the int part of the value. Any suggestions for improvement of my code are welcomed

Comment: Far from PC but try `Dictionary<string, (int RowNumber, bool Value)>`, then try `issueRowValidationDictionary['keyRef'].RowNumber`

Comment: Don't inherit Dictionary. Don't use tuple. Define a simple data structure with two properties and on the consumer side work with the generic IDictionary<string, YourStruct>.